# How to upload an image to the google drive using ionic angular

Tags: angular, image, ionic-framework, upload, drive

How to upload an image to the google drive using ionic angular(Android).
I need to connect my ionic app to google drive. From the app,an image is saved to the google drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a back-end service that put the images in Google Drive. And connect your app with this service.

Backend code example for this case:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public ModelAndView upload(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file, HttpSession session) {  
    String path = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");  
    String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();  

    System.out.println(path+" "+filename);  
    try {  
        byte barr[] = file.getBytes();  

        // this code put the file in the path 
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(  
             new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + filename));  
        bout.write(barr);  
        bout.flush();  
        bout.close();  
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }  

    return new ModelAndView("upload-success", "filename", path + "/" + filename);  
}
```

You should change the code that puts the file in a folder to another code that stores the file in Google Drive.

Code in your app:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE'
  })
};

uploadImage(url: string, param: any): Observable<any> {
  const body = JSON.stringify(param);
  console.log(body);
  return this.http
    .post(url, body, httpOptions);
}

uploadImage('Url to the back-service', image)
  .subscribe(
    result => {
      console.log('Image uploaded' + result);
    },
    error => console.log(error)
 );
```

Comment: actually image is generated in the app .i want to save that image to the google drive

Comment: yes, you should make a post request to the back service with the image, and the back service should storage the image.   I will put an exmple in the answer.

Comment: You should look in this page: [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) @Beginner

Comment: If we want to upload a data in user's drive.so if user wants they can remove it by themselves. this case will not work with this